# how to get multiple column distinct value and either diffrent field has same data in reverse

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 column named msg, sender and receiver. Now i need to get the distinct sender and receiver. but in here if i have sender a and receiver b Or sender b and receiver a, it is showing me both. but i want only last one.

```
msg | sender | receiver
hi  | 1      | 5
he  | 2      | 6
jh  | 5      |1

SELECT DSTINCT `sender`, `receiver` from `table`
```

it is giving me this result

```
1-5
2-6
5-1
```

but i need

```
5-1
2-6
```

is there any sql query that can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, let's use the fact that thy're integers and always put the smaller one on the first column and the bigger one in the right column

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN sender < receiver THEN sender ELSE receiver END as PartyA,
  CASE WHEN sender < receiver THEN receiver ELSE sender END as PartyB
from `table`
```

It doesnt exactly produce 5-1 (it produces 1-5) but I'm thinking you don't really care, you just want the unique list of people who had a conversation, and 5-1 == 1-5

Comment: Tnx bro, that helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using  `least()` and `greatest()` functions

```
select distinct least(sender , receiver), greatest(sender , receiver) 
from t
```